Ubuntu Studio 24.04 midi not working, distorted sound
I set up Ubuntu Studio 24.04 on a new machine. Audio works great, but midi - using fluidsynth - is very distorted.
A hardware midi out works.
This worked great on 20.04 and still on 22.04. How can I fix this? Is here anybody with a working midi configuration on 24.04?

adjusting soundcard buffer to 256 or lower resolves the problem. Using Ubuntu Studio audio configuration gui-tool.
